# Getting value of a php variable from database after an ajax call for a successive ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
var friendRequestURL = "scripts_for_profile/request_as_friend.php";
function addAsFriend(a,b) {
$("#add_friend_loader").show();
$.post(friendRequestURL,{ request: "requestFriendship", mem1: a, mem2: b,   thisWipit: thisRandNum } ,function(data) {
$("#add_friend").html(data).show().fadeOut(12000);
$("#friends").html('<div id="land"><a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers(\'cancel_request\');" >Cancel Request</a></div>').show();
}); 
}

function cancel_request(x) {
$.post(friendRequestURL,{ request: "cancel", reqID: x, thisWipit: thisRandNum } ,function(data) {
    $("#cancel_request").html(data).show().fadeOut(12000);
    $("#land").html('<div id="friends"><a href="#" onclick="return false"   onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers(\'add_friend\');">Add as Friend</a></div>').show();
});
}
```

This are functions which send friend requests to the people and when the request is sent the option of "Add as Friend" changes to "Cancel Request".

```
function toggleInteractContainers(x) {
    if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
        $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $('#'+x).hide();
    }
    $('.interactContainers').hide();
```

}

This function calls the toggle button like if user clicks on "Add as friend" then it asks for options "Yes" or "Cancel".

The php code is

```
<div id="land"><a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers(\'cancel_request\');" >Cancel Request</a></div>

<div id="friends"><a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers(\'add_friend\');">Add as Friend</a></div>


          <div class="interactContainers" id="add_friend" style="float:right; margin-right:100px; margin-top:0px;">
           Really?
            <a href="#" onClick="return false" onMouseDown="javascript:addAsFriend(<?php echo $logOptions_id; ?>, <?php echo $id; ?>);">Yes</a>
            <a href="#" onClick="return false" onMouseDown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers('add_friend');">cancel</a> 
      </div>

          <div class="interactContainers" id="cancel_request" style="float:right; margin-right:100px; margin-top:0px;">
           Really?
            <a href="#" onClick="return false" onMouseDown="javascript:cancel_request(<?php echo $requestID ; ?>)">Yes</a>
            <a href="#" onClick="return false" onMouseDown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers('cancel');">cancel</a> 
      </div>
```

The php code is not at a single place but is scattered around the page. My problem is that the code works fine in the first place. Like if user clicks on "Add as friend" then it asks them "Really" or "cancel". Then if user click "really" then the "Add as friend" changes to "Cancel Request" and a request is sent to the user. Then if user clicks on "Cancel Request" without a page refresh then also it works fine and asks "really" or "cancel" and if user clicks on "really" then request is cancelled but if he clicks "cancel" then the request is not cancelled.

So basically the problem is that if the request is sent and the page is not refreshed then the request id ` 
is not being updated and so we are not able to cancel the request.

**Is there anyway that I can get back the value of the requestID without page refresh**

In scripts_for_profile/request_as_friend.php the following is the code to insert the friend request in the database.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends_requests (mem1, mem2, timedate)     VALUES('$mem1','$mem2',now())") or die (mysql_error("Friend Request Insertion Error"));
```

Answer (score 0):

An example straight from the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ :

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

`data` is the output of *test.php* which gets sent back to your `$.post` function's callback. So in your PHP file *scripts_for_profile/request_as_friend.php* where you are doing the server side update, you can echo out the request ID and it will be returned like the above example.

Another way in your PHP is to create an object and then JSON encode it so when it gets returned, you have JSON to use in your Javascript.

```
<?php
   // Do some database stuff here
   ...

   // Create object
   $obj = new stdClass();

   // Store requestID in your object (however it is that you choose to get it)
   $obj->requestID = getRequestID();

   // Encode object as JSON and echo out
   $result = json_encode($obj);

   echo($result);
?>
```

You'll probably also want to set your headers to have a json/text type.

Comment: Okay I echoed the rqstid as $rqst so how can I use it in the script without echoing the value. I just want to use the value and store it in a php variable.

Comment: If you are trying to keep the variable server side (I thought you wanted to use it in your Javascript), then why not just grab it from the database when you need it?

Comment: No but I want to get the value using an ajax call and then use it in the php script

Comment: By time your page loads and you are able to make an AJAX call...that PHP script has already run and completed. The only way to get a value from your AJAX call and use it in a PHP script, is to pass it as a parameter in another HTTP request (ex. GET or POST). You should read up on the differences between server side and client side processing.

Comment: Okay if I get the data from the php file using echo and get the result and use regular expression to get the request id and then pass it as the parameter to the function

Comment: can't we store the requestID in a session variable and then change the session variable so that the requestID is updated when the friendrequest is send